# Linq for nested object in cosmos db json

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

Hi there I cant figure out euivalent of this cosmos query in linq

Cosmos Query:

```
select c_option
from c
join c_size in c.size
join c_variant in c_size.variant
join c_option in c_variant.option
where c.type = 'product'
and c_option.optionID = '869'
```

And my linq but it returns null all the time ehh.

```
query.SelectMany(product => product.Size
.SelectMany(size => size.Variant
.SelectMany(variant => variant.Option
.Where(option => option.OptionId
.Equals(optionId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))))));
```

Option is nested child object in product . Nesting looks like that product->size->variant->option

Product Model is a class with properties of type int/string and also collection of size

```
public class Product {
 int id {get;set;}
 IList<Size> Size {get;set;}
}
```

```
public class Size {
 int id {get;set;}
 IList<Variant> Variant {get;set;}
}
```

```
public class Variant {
 int id {get;set;}
 IList<Option> Options {get;set;}
}
```

```
public class Option {
 int id {get;set;}
 IList<OptionAvailability> OptionsAvas {get;set;}
}
```

Result: I need to get an option by option Id

Comment: Please show your model, it is hard to understand what is here. Also, what is `query`?

Comment: can you tell an example of what result are you expecting?? its not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tured out I got a spelling issue in the json property, optionID instead of optionId. Besides that everything works now.

Cheers.

Comment: Could you please accept as an answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you